Proving a recursive sequence is Cauchy by definition
I’m new here and do not have access to a computer (am using my phone), so hopefully you’ll pardon me for not employing LaTeX.
My question is as follows:

Let $a>0$. The sequence $(x_n)$ is defined by:
$$x_{n+1}=1+\frac1{x_n}\text{ and }x_1=a.$$
Prove that the sequence is Cauchy, strictly by definition.

I’m well acquainted with the conditions for a sequence to be Cauchy.
However, it is not clear to me whether this should be handled by assigning indices m,n (or p, based on an alternative definition) actual values (randomly) and then try to express epsilon in terms of the given parameter a (or a in terms of epsilon), which conflicts with choosing m,n which are greater than N_epsilon (an expression for which I do not know how to derive in this case), or rather adhere to m,n (or p) and derive a general expression for |x_m - x_n| (or |x_(n+p) - x_n|) while demonstrating it is less than epsilon?
I hope my question is sufficiently lucid. I’d happily rephrase if need be.
Thank you for any comments.

Mathjax tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

What exactly does strictly by definition mean? Are we allowed to solve the recurrence relation?

@Pranay hence, one’s to show that either |x_n - x_m|<epsilon, for m,n>N, where N depends normally on epsilon itself and for every positive epsilon. Alternatively, show that |x_(n+p) - x_n|<epsilon, for every epsilon greater than zero and every natural number p s.t. n>N where N, again usually, is a function of epsilon. One is to avoid using any deductions based on convergence etc., just the very rudimentary definition.

Hint: prove  $$\exists k\in[0,1),;\exists N,;\forall n\ge N,;|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|\le k|x_{n+1}-x_n|.$$

I didn’t have a deduction based on convergence in mind. I was actually thinking of solving the recurrence relation for all $n$ (it’s not hard to solve it) and then show that it’s Cauchy. But I guess you don’t want to solve it.

Prove successively:
$$\forall n\ge1\quad x_n>0$$
$$\forall n\ge2\quad x_n>1$$
$$\forall n\ge2\quad|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|\le\frac{|x_{n+1}-x_n|}2$$
$$\forall n\ge2\quad|x_{n+1}-x_n|\le2^{2-n}|x_3-x_2|$$
$$\forall m\ge n\ge2\quad|x_m-x_n|\le2^{3-n}|x_3-x_2|.$$

If the step from the second line to the third turns out too tricky, I suggest an intermediate step $$\forall n\ge2\quad x_{n+1} x_n > 2.$$

This is equivalent to the second line. And the most natural way to the 3rd line leads to your suggestion.

@AnneBauval First, although I just proved by induction the validity of the inequality on the fourth line, how did you arrive at it or rather what was the rationale that led you to phrase it. Second, proving that this series is Cauchy strictly by definition requires the use of epsilon, i.e. I am to show that |x_m - x_n|<= epsilon>0, whereas |x_3 - x_2|=|a^2 - a - 1|/(a(a + 1))

@AnneBauval how do you account for that seeming discrepancy?


I don't know if you are asking about the general scheme of the proof (which is a ususal trick, as first hinted above), or about the step from 3rd to 4th line. 2) For every $\epsilon>0$, for $n$ large enough we have $2^{3-n}|x_3-x_2|<\epsilon$. The value of $|x_3-x_2|$ does not matter.


@AnneBauval 1) I was evidemment inquiring specifically about the rationale leading to line 4 based upon line 3. And 2) am I not required to show that there indeed exists such n or even explicitly formulate it in terms of epsilon?


The question was not obvious (at least to me, whence my query for clarification). See for instance here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3925759 2) Matter of taste: either formulate it explicitely (which is not difficult), or just note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{3-n}|x_3-x_2|=0$.


@AnneBauval 1) Thank you, that certainly elucidates that. And 2) how did you know how to select your m,n accordingly? Their infimum or highest lower bound should be written in terms of epsilon so it applies to every epsilon>0. I presume it’s not critical as the inequality would still hold and m,n meet that criterion, and yet… Finally, 3) why were we given the parameter a if not to somehow make use of it and its properties in the proof? We merely used its positivity, but not it per se. Was it simply to generalize the problem? It could have similarly just been stipulated that x_1 was positive.

@AnneBauval Excuse me, I didn’t intend continuing this on chat. Although perhaps we should.


FIne! 2) I select m,n a posteriori: given $\epsilon>0$, I select $m\ge n\ge N$ with $N$ chosen large enough, so that $2^{3-N}|x_3-x_2|<\epsilon$, i.e. $N>3+\log_2\frac{|x_3-x_2|}\epsilon$. 3) I completely agree.

